# Text of differential geometry

Tags: reference-request

I would like to ask for suggestions for a differential geometry text book, reaching the theory of $n$-dimensional (not only cuves and surfaces) differentiable and Riemannian manifolds in sight of applications to the study of the theory of relativity.
Since, when a text proposes exercises, it often uses the results derived in them to prove following lemmas and theorems, and since I don't attend classes at the university and have not the opportunity to ask professors about solutions, I would need a text including solutions to the proposed exercises (or a text that doesn't use the results proved in the exercises to prove the theory), which are quite rare to find in "intermediate" to advanced texts. I find it very frustrating to solve exercises and to be left with the doubt I convinced myself of wrong ideas. I prefer a book lacking exercises (which can be found on the net) than a book using results of exercises in the theory part, but not showing the solutions to the exercises.
I can use texts in Italian, English, Spanish, Portuguese and French.
Thank you so much for any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite fond of Sternberg's *Curvature in Mathematics and Physics*. It's available online [here](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1048774.files/132bookrevised2011.pdf), and for buying, [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486478556). The book covers all that you've listed. It also doesn't contain any exercises, except in the first two chapters, which set the basis for the book - so the exercises in the first two chapters just provide you with a strong foundation.

Comment: The lack of exercises isn't a problem: you can find tons of them elsewhere. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavideZena Sure!

Comment: The link to the online (draft?) version at `isites.harvard.edu` is broken, but a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140602111331/http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1048774.files/132bookrevised2011.pdf).